# Build multimodule project with special profile for a special module

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I have a multimodule project I build it with oracle profile that I use for Module 1 and Module 2.

[image]

Using this Maven command from Parent : `mvn clean install -Poracle`

I want to keep the actual profile (***oracle***) for All Modules except Module 3 and choose for it another profile ( ***X or Y*** ) that i will use it later for resource filtering  as you can see in the picture.

Questions :

1) Is it possible?

2) How can I do it ( configuration in Parent + Module 3 pom.xml && maven command )

Comment: Why do you need the profile `oracle` ?

Comment: Oracle is used for module 1 and 2 ( jdbc config and some filtering )

Comment: I would make a separate module war which is special for Oracle without profile and the resources as well...furthermore why do you need the resource filtering based on a profile?

Comment: I use resource filtering based on profile to select wich Oracle datasource infos I should use, ( profile X = Production , profile Y = Local ...)

Comment: Separation of concern and make a suggested before a separate module which handles all that. That will remove the need for profiles and makes your easier and more reproducible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

You can, though, define "marker files" in the different modules that trigger whether a profile is active or not (so if there is a file `oracle.txt`, then the oracle profile is run).